# Parent above child on the z-axis in css / html

Tags: html, css, parent-child

I have a div (the parent) and another div in the parent (the child) and I want to hide the child behind the parent.

**edit** : I will try to explain better, so i speak about the z axis but if i do something like :

```css
.parent {
  z-index: 10;
}

.child {
  z-index: 0;
}
```

it's not working. So i ask you the question : how my child can be under my parent on the z axis ?

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.child {
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try setting the width and height first.

Comment: What do you mean "hide the child behind the parent"? I mean, setting `display: none` on the child would hide it, irrespective of its position relative to the parent. Please add more details to your question about exactly what you are trying to achieve. Please also show what attempts and research you've done.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I mean the child is under the parent on the z axis. And i will edit my question

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Edited, i hope you will understand my question (my english is not very good).

Comment: Would `visibility: hidden` work for you? :)

Comment: @ManojKumar nah it's not what i search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will use z-index.
**z-index** only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

```css
.parent {
  background-color: red;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}

.child {
  background-color: blue;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  position:relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, it fixed my problem.

Comment: @Crayzzit Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try again with `position: relative;`

Answer (score 1):

davecar21 beat me to it, but basically the child needs to be `position: relative` with `z-index: -1`.

However, I would like to add that positioning the child behind its parent feels like an antipattern.  To me, z-indexing represents layering between siblings, so if possible, I would recommend restructuring your approach such that the parent-child elements are actually adjacent siblings, perhaps nested in some containing element.

Comment: Good point @Auroratide.